# Python permission error on windows 10 when moving/renaming file

Tags: python

I'm just trying to rename a file or move it to another directory. Either option will work for me. I have the most basic code here that I could find on the internet (first python project here by the way).

```
import shutil
import os

while True:
    for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc1"):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            shutil.move("C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc1/" + file, "C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc2/moved.txt")
            # os.rename("C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc1/" + file, "C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc2/moved.txt")
```

But no matter what I try, i ALWAYS get this error in my console when running the file:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc1/i000130126543220150615123030.txt' -> 'C:/Users/lines/OneDrive/Desktop/loc2/moved.txt'
```

I truly have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Edit: both directories are totally empty and only being used for this test purpose. No other text editors have these files open anywhere.

Comment: Have you [verified](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) that there are no other processes are using those files?

Comment: they're just empty text files. no content. i'm just trying to get a feel for how to manipulate files for a project i want to start. I think somehow my script is causing an internal error within itself. If I drag a file into the folder being monitored, it works. if I copy/paste the file, it does not work. Also, if the file causes the permissions error, i can shut down the script and when I run the script immediately again, it moves the file like it should. Could my own script be holding itself up?

Comment: [Try to find out which process is locking the file](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: I can't replicate the error. Both Guy Shefer and myself have recommended checking what process is locking the file. Checking for external issues is an important part of the debugging process. Leaving it to fate is a good way to waste a lot of time trying to fix  code that is already functional.

Comment: so i added a time.sleep(2) as the first line of the while loop. that seems to have fixed it. i'm guessing the loop was running so fast that while the windows process of moving the file into the monitoring folder the loop would catch it half way through and throw the error.